# can someone explain the last argument of this function for me?

Tags: c++, pointers, hash, constructor

it's a constructor for a hash, but i don't understand the last argument. what is it doing?

```
std::fill(hash_table_, hash_table_ + HASH_TABLE_SIZE, (node *)NULL)
```

can you just do this in a for loop somehow?

```
for (int i = 0; i < HASH_TABLE_SIZE; i++){
    //whatever that last argument is doing
    hash_table_++;
}
```

trying to understand how fill works with hash. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

That line fills your hash table with NULLs.

Yes, you can also use a loop, but it is more work and more error-prone.

Answer (score 0):

It sets the whole hash table to the last argument (NULL), a loop for that will be:

```
for (int i = 0; i < HASH_TABLE_SIZE; i++)
{
    *(hash_table_ + i) = (node *)NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> i don't understand the last argument. what is it doing?
>
> std::fill(hash_table_, hash_table_ + HASH_TABLE_SIZE, (node *)NULL)

Is it filling a hash table with `NULL` pointers to `node`.

> can you just do this in a for loop somehow?

```
for (int i = 0; i < HASH_TABLE_SIZE; i++){
    hash_table_[i] = (node*)NULL;
}
```